# Rails JS files and layouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a few pages for a rails site and my js files are being confused.  I would like to know what the best practice for handling page specific js while still using the rails asset pipeline.

My guess is that my problem is being caused because of the onload functions in separate files compiling into one, but I could be wrong.

I have a landing page that runs the following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      getQuote();
      $('#get-quote').on('click', getQuote);
      $('#btn-twitter').on('click', function() {openURL(url);});
    });
function getQuote() {
      $.when($.ajax( {
      url: 'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1',
      success: function(data) {
        var post = data.shift();
        var author = post.title;
        if($(post.content).text().length > 250) {
          getQuote();
        } else {
          var quote = $(post.content).text();
          setTweetText(quote, author);
          $('#quote-author').html(author);
          $('#quote-content').html(quote);
        }
      },
      cache: false
    })).then(function(){
      $('#content').show();
      $('#msg').hide();
    })
}

function openURL(url){
  window.open(url, 'Share', 'width=550, height=400, toolbar=0, scrollbars=1 ,location=0 ,statusbar=0,menubar=0, resizable=0');
}
var url = "";
function setTweetText(quote, author) {
  url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(quote + " -" + author);
}
```

Then once they hit the homepage, the layout template runs the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("dd-button").addEventListener("click", ddClicked);
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('#dd-button')) {
            document.getElementById("dd-menu").classList.remove("dd-show");
        }
    }

    function ddClicked() {
        console.log("dd clicked");
        document.getElementById('dd-menu').classList.add("dd-show");
    }
});
```

I get errors like the following on both pages:

```
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Any help on ordering my code is appreciated.

Comment: `$` is a error for jQuery.. 1. U are not including it or 2. U're loading jQuery after ur js file and `addEventListener` error it's gonna be because it cannot find any element with that ID.

Comment: Let me clarify, the code is working correctly, so if I'm on the landing page the jQuery error is not showing up. The problem is that the error shows up on a page that does not use the particular block of code.  So if I'm not on the landing page then I get a jQuery message. Does that make sense